# Can I use a Virtual Machine for Linux Kernel Drivers Development?

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I'm currently reading the book called `Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition`, here is a link to it, but I'm sure that most of you that experienced are already familiar with it:

https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/

I just got to `Chapter 2`. And generally speaking, it's about setting up the basic kernel programming environment. For educational purposes, this book almost all the time (except one example at the end) relies only on `built-in` hardware, like discs, etc. Therefore my question is:
Can I use a virtual machine (I'm currently using `Ubuntu 18.04` on `VirtualBox` with `5.3 Kernel`) for this book? I know that VMs have their own Kernels. So can I go through this book, write char drivers, etc using the `VirtualBox` instead of a real machine? And is it safe? Because the main reason I want to do this is to avoid damaging my girl system. For now I, unfortunately, don't have any additional hardware on which I could run another system to test things on. Would a Ubuntu VM be enough for that book?

NOTE: I have seen similar posts but I would like to make another one because here I specify what I'm going to do with it, that is, follow the examples of this book. Therefore ask is a VM is enough at least for THOSE examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do all that on a VM, and yes, it is safe inasmuch as it will prevent you from damaging your system. You can do all the examples on virtualized hardware. Be aware, though, that the kernel has evolved quite a bit since the publication of that book, so you may have to adapt a few bits when working on a current kernel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a VM for driver development.

If you do not use paravirtualized hardware (virtio) then the virtual hardware of a VM behaves towards a kernel module like real hardware would.

I do not know that book but if the examples would work with the real hardware which is emulated by the hypervisor then the respective virtual hardware should be fine for that purpose.

With PCI passthrough it may even be feasable to develop hardware for a real hardware attached to the host system.

Comment: @John I thought I had said that but I made it clearer. I have also added another thought to the answer.